# Group Policy Confusion (Printers configured under users?)

Tags: windows, printer, active-directory, group-policy

I'm befuddled. Active directory usually makes a bit more sense than this.

The Problem: Referencing the images below (with private info removed), it appears that Printer Connections are being defined beneath User Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings, but "Printer Connections" doesn't exist in that location in the editor view of the policy. I've been asked to remove the printer definitions from the User Configuration section of the policy, and I'm stuck. [image: Printscreen1][image: Printscreen2]

Additional Info: The main reason for removing the printer definitions from User configuration is to reduce boot time & log in time for VPN users. The policy being altered is the Default Domain Policy as is visible in the images. We have other Policies in other OUs (everything else has been blanked for security purposes), but this one is the relevant policy. The functional level of the domain is Windows Server 2008. The domain controllers are both Server 2008 Enterprise without Hyper-V. *Note: Server 2008 R2 is not implemented.* If I left out something pertinent, leave a comment & I'll comment/respond or edit accordingly.

Question: **Where is the correct location to configure user-based printer configuration and/or printer definition deployment?**

Bonus points: **Why is it displaying in this manner?** This just doesn't make sense to me.

If I'm going about this all wrong, a shove in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can use a logon script?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't preferred. The intent is to alter the Group Policy settings to remove printers from the User Configuration, but retain them at the Computer Configuration.

Comment: Suggestion: Use GPP, it appears you have it, it's _much_ nicer for printers and drive mapping. You can target things so easily. 'These users get this printer, but not if they're in this IP range' (for example) is sooo easy to setup.

Comment: I just checked one of our 2K8 R2 machines, it's not in there for us either.  My suggestion (_guess_) would be try installing the "Print and Document Services" role on the same server you're doing GP editing on.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the print management feature to your domain controller. It will add the Deployed Printers option within group policy which is where these printers will show up.